# Matlab error using matrix logical indexing A(I) = B

Tags: matlab, matrix

Trying to do a matrix logical indexing, but Matlab seems to be crazy, what I'm missing here?

Look:

```
>> A
A =
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
>> B
B =
     1     2     3     4
>> I
I =
     1     1     0     0
>> A(I) = B
In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must
be the same. 
>> numel(B)
ans =
     4
>> numel(A)
ans =
     4
```

Comment: `B` has 4 elements and `I` only has 2 TRUE elements and you can't coerce 4 elements into 2. Maybe `A(I) = B(I)`? Also this is called logical indexing not "flag operation"

Comment: The other 2 should be kept unchanged. I guess.

Comment: Did you try what I just posted? It does exactly that.

Comment: A(I) = B(I) works. Ok, it makes sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rest assured, MATLAB isn't crazy. `B` has 4 elements as you've shown and `A(I)` only has 2 because `I` only has 2 `true` values.

```
numel(B)
%   4

numel(A(I))
%   2
```

You are trying to assign 4 elements into two elements in `A` is which is exactly what your error states.

> In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same

You can only assign two values from `B` into `A` with your specific value if `I`. I'm guessing you would want to only assign the corresponding elements of `B` like this.

```
A(I) = B(I);
```